# Iterating a part of a string

Tags: python, json, string, for-loop

I want to extract some data for which I have the following code:

```
import http.client

conn = http.etc("something")

headers = {
    'id': "asdfghjk",
    'accept': "application/json"
    }

conn.request("GET", "/SomeLocationData?latitude=50&longitude=10&time=631152000", headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Now,  I want to extract all the data starting from latitude 45 and ending at 55, and the same for longitude and time. So for each one I have a range and I need all the possible combinations. How do I write a for loop for every value that is inside that string?

Edit: this is the code that I use to extract the data from a service and I only input the values for latitude, longitude and time. The output is something like:

```
[{"contentVersion":1,"location":{"latitude":48.003,"longitude":15.998001,"time":1597287600},"precipitation":-999,"symbolCode":-999,"temperature":15,"windDirection":190.22656,"windSpeed":0.015625}]
```

Comment: Without any information about data format we can't help you.

Comment: Please provide a sample input data (all your provided code is irrelevant to your problem) and expected output

Comment: That all depends on that the data looks like.  This is not reproducible ... please make reproducible and share the data content.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, do you mean something like `for lat,lon,t in itertools.product(range(45,55),(45,46),(1,20)): print (lat,lon,t)`?

Comment: @JanStránský obviously with range in front of every pair. How do I plug it in the string, though?

Comment: @Fabulini what does "plug in the string" mean?

Comment: @JanStránský in my original code, the values of lat, lon, t, are inside of a string and I replace them manually. What do I do such that it automatically iterates over the output that we obtained in the for-loop?

Comment: @Fabulini it would be good if you update the code such that it shows 1) your actual problem (and nothing more), 2) some sample input and 3) expected output. As you see from the comments, it is really confusing in the current form..

Comment: conn.request("GET", f"/SomeLocationData?latitude={lat}&longitude={lon}&time={t}", headers=headers) I guess this is what you mean by 'plug in the string'.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone said, it depends on the data that you are getting from GET method, as of now for better understanding I am showing for a below sample JSON.

Let us consider this is the output that we get from the GET method.

```
[
{
    "contentVersion": 1,
    "location": {
        "latitude": 48.003,
        "longitude": 15.998001,
        "time": 1597287600
    },
    "precipitation": -999,
    "symbolCode": -999,
    "temperature": 15,
    "windDirection": 190.22656,
    "windSpeed": 0.015625
},
{
    "contentVersion": 2,
    "location": {
        "latitude": 58.003,
        "longitude": 5.998001,
        "time": 1297287600
    },
    "precipitation": -999,
    "symbolCode": -999,
    "temperature": 15,
    "windDirection": 190.22656,
    "windSpeed": 0.015625
},
{
    "contentVersion": 1,
    "location": {
        "latitude": 40.003,
        "longitude": 51.998001,
        "time": 1097287600
    },
    "precipitation": -999,
    "symbolCode": -999,
    "temperature": 15,
    "windDirection": 190.22656,
    "windSpeed": 0.015625
    }
]
```

Below is the code that we can fetch for respective values.

```
for x in range(len(data)):
    lati = int(data[x]['location']['latitude'])
    
    # Getting Latitude on a range
    if lati > 45 and lati > 50:
        print(lati)
        
    # Same way for the other two
```

For the above code using the above JSON, the output of Latitude will be 58 only.